# Kafka consumer proceed hanging awaiting messages when connection is lost

Tags: python, apache-kafka, listener, aio

I am using [aiokafka==0.5.2](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiokafka) as python lib for kafka

I have just the code form the [example](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiokafka#aiokafkaconsumer):

```
async def consume():
    consumer = AIOKafkaConsumer(
        'my_topic', 'my_other_topic',
        loop=loop, bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
        group_id="my-group")

    await consumer.start()
    try:
        # Consume messages
        async for msg in consumer:
            #...
```

When I run it - it works fine. But when I stop Kafka server - my app proceed hanging waiting for messages. And, I guess, when prod server exclude Kafka node from balancing - my app know nothing about this. How could I have listener on Kafka connection inside my app?

Comment: Did you figure out the problem? I am facing a similar issue with aiokafka==0.5.2

Comment: Hanging waiting for kafka restart is expected behavior. 
My issue that when rebalancing occurs - new messages doesn't come. It what i have on servers, but I wasn't able to reproduce it locally.